# Better way to compare two datasets in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm coming up against a tricky challenge.  Let me explain what I'm trying to make happen.  If a user logs into my app with Facebook, I scrape all their facebook friends UIDs and store these as the users 'facebook_friends'.  Then, once logged in, the user sees a list of events that are upcoming, and I want to check on each event if any of the attendees match a UID of the user's facebook friends and highlight this to them.

I've opted to create the Event.rb model as follows:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  #  id                  :integer(11)

  has_many :attendances, as: :attendable
  has_many :attendees

  def which_facebook_friends_are_coming_for(user)
    matches = []
    self.attendees.each do |attendee|
      matches << user.facebook_friends.where("friend_uid=?", attendee.facebook_id)
    end
    return matches
  end

end
```

You can see that I've created the **which_facebook_friends_are_coming_for(user)** method, but it strikes me as incredibily inefficient.  When I run it from the console, it does work, but if I try and dump it in any form (like YAML), I get told **can't dump anonymous module**.  I'm presuming this is because now the 'matches' holder isn't a class as such (when it should be FacebookFriends).

There must be a better way to do this and I'd love some suggestions.

For reference, the other classes look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #  id                  :integer(11)

  has_many :attendances, foreign_key: :attendee_id, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :facebook_friends

end


class FacebookFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  #  user_id             :integer(11)
  #  friend_uid          :string
  #  friend_name         :string

  belongs_to :user

end


class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  #  attendee_id         :integer(11)
  #  attendable_type     :string
  #  attendable_id       :integer(11)

  belongs_to :attendable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like that:

```
def which_facebook_friends_are_coming_for(user)
  self.attendees.map(&:facebook_id) & user.facebook_friends.map(&:friend_uid)
end
```

The & operator simply returns the intersection of two arrays